Which proposal function should be used in this particular case of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?
As part of my research, I would like to apply the Metropolis-Hastings in order to sample from some posterior distribution. More precisely, the data comes from a multivariate normal distribution in the presence of censorship and the prior has normal-inverse-wishart distribution (the covariance matrix has inverse-wishart distribution and the mean conditioned on the covariance matrix has normal distribution). One possible proposal distribution for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm consists in using the prior distributions itself since it is easy to sample from it. However the acceptance ratio is generally very low and the algorithm evolves quite slowly. Having said that, I would like to know if anyone could provide me some guidance on the subject, that is to say, I would be interested in knowing if the choice for the prior distribution is acceptable as well as whether there exists another proposal distribution which is more efficient.
Any help is appreciated.

Do you specifically want to use Metropolis-Hastings coded yourself? Because (a) the posterior is available analytically for that conjugate prior, and (b) software such as JAGS or Stan will probably do a better job of designing the MCMC for you

@ThomasLumley I know that the posterior is normal-inverse-wishart when the data is complete. But the same claim is true in the presence of censorship (such as interval-censorship)? I prefer to code it myself. Nonetheless, if there is already a package, I do not bother to use it.

Ok, yes, for censored data it probably won't be analytically tractable. I missed that.

Are you familiar with the random walk proposal? If not, I can write up a short answer about it. As long as your parameter space isn't huge (or can be blocked into smaller chunks), and your problem isn't too complex, it usually works fairly well.

Using the prior distribution is usually a poor choice, unless it is used in combination with other kernels as a refreshment step. In the current problem, a Gibbs sampler would seem most appropriate as generating the censored data would allow for using the full data posterior on the parameters.

@AdamCheck Please tell me more about such proposal distribution.

@Xi'an Thanks for the comment. But how do I determine the marginal distributions in order to apply the Gibbs Sampling? The likelihood corresponds to a multivariate normal distribution in the presence of censorship.

@Xi'an I did not grasp what you mean by "a Gibbs sampler would seem most appropriate as generating the censored data would allow for using the full data posterior on the parameters" (sorry, I am not fluent in English).

There are likely efficient Gibbs Samplers for this type of problem (as noted in the comment by Xi'an) - for example, Gary Koop's textbooks (here and here) cover Tobit (censored) regression models.
If you want to use a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, you could try using a random walk proposal. The random walk proposal usually uses a normal distribution, centered at the current parameter value(s). The SD of this normal distribution needs to be set appropriately by the researcher. If you have more than one parameter, each can have a unique SD.
For example, suppose $\theta^{(s-1)}$ is the value of the parameter vector from the previous iteration. We propose a new value $\theta^* \sim N \left (\theta^{(s-1)},\sigma \right )$.
To calibrate the SD of the random walk proposal, a simple method is to monitor the acceptance rate of their MH chain. If the acceptance rate is too low, the SD of their proposal is too large, and needs to be reduced before running the chain again. If the acceptance rate is too small, the random walk steps are too small, so the SD needs to be increased. Typically, acceptance rates between 25%-50% work well in practice.
A major benefit to using the normal random walk proposal, is that the proposal distribution is symmetric, so you don't need to worry about it when calculating the MH acceptance probability. A major downside is that the parameter draws will be autocorrelated, so the sampler is not particularly efficient.
